# Is there a program similar to Adobe Capture for Linux?

Tags: gratis, linux, image-editor, screenshot, graphic-design

I love the ***shape capturing*** feature in the **Adobe Capture** mobile app. I use it all the time to convert images and drawings into clip art.

On my computer, I use **GIMP** and there is no official way to get those captures to **GIMP** unless I use an **Adobe** product for PC (which I do not have access to).

Are there any alternatives to **Adobe Capture** available to use for free?

Comment: Just a note for Linux users familiar with only rectangular captures -- _shape capturing_ allows various adjustable capture shapes, (circle, elipse, *n*-gon, star, etc.), plus *freehand*, all in one step.  I.E. without the hassle of capturing a rectangle, copying it into gimp, and cutting out a shape.

Comment: I believe this would be a nice feature request for [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/).